# Is there a way of adding <strong> tags in Wordpress's description/tagline area

Tags: wordpress

In **Wordpress administrator -> Settings** there's a tagline / description field:

For example:

```
<div id="tagline"><p><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p></div>
```

description: `I'm a <strong>web</strong> and graphic designer`

But it seems like it only allows text not HTMl tags.

Is there any way of doing this o I have to create a new field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is run through a filter that replaces HTML entities, so even if you were to run a filter on that option(which is possible), WordPress replaces the HTML entities, meaning HTML wouldn't work...

For example, add this code and watch what happens.

```
add_filter( 'option_blogdescription', 'html_blog_description' );
function html_blog_description( $option_value ) {
    $option_value = '<strong>Test text </strong>'. $option_value;
    return $option_value;
}
```

There aren't any hooks i can see that specifically deal with this option and convert the entities, else i'd have ideas about unhooking that action from the description.

I think the only solution you really have is to run `str_replace` over your calls to fecth the blog description. This would mean updating all your calls for `bloginfo( 'description' )` with a rountine that performs string replacement on the content.

eg.

```
$description = str_replace(' web ','<strong> web </strong>',get_bloginfo('description'));
echo $description;
```

Sure it's not ideal, but i can't currently see a more elegant way(though i'd be happy for someone to prove me wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You could just change it in your stylesheet.

```
#tagline {font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself very well. I meant to add `<strong>` tags in just few words of the description (not the whole paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

Use `html_entity_decode` combined with `get_bloginfo` (instead of `bloginfo`). So replace:

```php
    <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>
```

By:

```php
    <?php echo html_entity_decode( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>
```

*Note: Tested on WordPress 3.8.1.*